# Sticky footer overlaps content on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, footer, sticky-footer

My intention is to have the footer fixed at the bottom of the page and appear behind content (not overlap it). It works fine on Mozilla. Pictures and codes below:

On Mozilla:
[image: Mozilla Firefox footer]

On IE 11:
[image: Internet Explorer footer]

```css
.stage{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    min-height:700px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-bottom:100px;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #666666;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid #BAC2C5 1px;
    border-top: solid #BAC2C5 0px;
    position:relative;
}

.footer-box{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    height:35px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    z-index:initial;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="stage">
            Content goes Here
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer-box">
                Footer goes Here
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sadly I can't link the page so the code/pictures are examples that demonstrate what is happening

Edit: Changing z-index to -1 hides it completely on IE (it's still there, just under 'stage'), still works on Firefox.

Edit: Removed margin-top:100px from footer-box since it did not have any effect

Comment: Probably the margin-top on .footer-box. You can remove it; it won't have any effect anyways. But really hard to say for sure without having a working example.

Comment: That is one of the things I added while trying to fix it. It indeed doesn't do anything, so I'll remove it from the example (which doesn't fix it)

Comment: Could you try to set up `body,html{width:100%; height: 100%}`

Comment: Didn't change anything

Comment: I spun up a VM with IE10 and 11 at https://codepen.io/niorad/pen/xpoROZ and it seems to look good. Could you check this one?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf9TX.png doesn't work here, any clue on why (I also tested it on my original code, no changes sadly)?